# Make can't do this harmless command

Tags: iphone, gcc, build

I am using make on linux. I downloaded the GCC source code from
`svn checkout svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk`
and I got gcc version 4.6.0. I then typed in:
`./configure --build=x86_64-fedora-linux-gnu --target=arm-apple-darwin --with-ecj-jar`
I'm running fedora 12 linux. I typed in --build because otherwise it configures it under x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.
My default build directory is /home/Leo/Documents/gcc-cross-iphone-4.6.0/
I then typed in make, and somewhere near the beginning I got error 2. I know that error 2 means that the program within make returned error 2. However, nothing appeared to have gone wrong. It just executed a bunch of commands, and make returned error 2. There was no echoed output that said foo happened it just said make ********* error 2.
This is the error message: (skip to the end for the actual message.)

```
gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2  -I. -I../.././libiberty/../include  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wc++-compat -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic   ../.././libiberty/physmem.c -o pic/physmem.o; \
    else true; fi
gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2  -I. -I../.././libiberty/../include  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wc++-compat -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic  ../.././libiberty/physmem.c -o physmem.o
if [ x"" != x ]; then \
      gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2  -I. -I../.././libiberty/../include  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wc++-compat -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic   ../.././libiberty/pex-common.c -o pic/pex-common.o; \
    else true; fi
yes
gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2  -I. -I../.././libiberty/../include  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wc++-compat -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic  ../.././libiberty/pex-common.c -o pex-common.o
checking for sys/stat.h... if [ x"" != x ]; then \
      gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2  -I. -I../.././libiberty/../include  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wc++-compat -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic   ../.././libiberty/pex-one.c -o pic/pex-one.o; \
    else true; fi
gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2  -I. -I../.././libiberty/../include  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wc++-compat -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic  ../.././libiberty/pex-one.c -o pex-one.o
if [ x"" != x ]; then \
      gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2  -I. -I../.././libiberty/../include  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wc++-compat -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic   ../.././libiberty/pex-unix.c -o pic/pex-unix.o; \
    else true; fi
gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2  -I. -I../.././libiberty/../include  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wc++-compat -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic  ../.././libiberty/pex-unix.c -o pex-unix.o
yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... rm -f ./libiberty.a pic/./libiberty.a
ar rc ./libiberty.a \
      ./regex.o ./cplus-dem.o ./cp-demangle.o ./md5.o ./sha1.o ./alloca.o ./argv.o ./choose-temp.o ./concat.o ./cp-demint.o ./crc32.o ./dyn-string.o ./fdmatch.o ./fibheap.o ./filename_cmp.o ./floatformat.o ./fnmatch.o ./fopen_unlocked.o ./getopt.o ./getopt1.o ./getpwd.o ./getruntime.o ./hashtab.o ./hex.o ./lbasename.o ./lrealpath.o ./make-relative-prefix.o ./make-temp-file.o ./objalloc.o ./obstack.o ./partition.o ./pexecute.o ./physmem.o ./pex-common.o ./pex-one.o ./pex-unix.o ./safe-ctype.o ./sort.o ./spaces.o ./splay-tree.o ./strerror.o ./strsignal.o ./unlink-if-ordinary.o ./xatexit.o ./xexit.o ./xmalloc.o ./xmemdup.o ./xstrdup.o ./xstrerror.o ./xstrndup.o  
ranlib ./libiberty.a
yes
checking for unistd.h... if [ x"" != x ]; then \
      cd pic; \
      ar rc ./libiberty.a \
        ./regex.o ./cplus-dem.o ./cp-demangle.o ./md5.o ./sha1.o ./alloca.o ./argv.o ./choose-temp.o ./concat.o ./cp-demint.o ./crc32.o ./dyn-string.o ./fdmatch.o ./fibheap.o ./filename_cmp.o ./floatformat.o ./fnmatch.o ./fopen_unlocked.o ./getopt.o ./getopt1.o ./getpwd.o ./getruntime.o ./hashtab.o ./hex.o ./lbasename.o ./lrealpath.o ./make-relative-prefix.o ./make-temp-file.o ./objalloc.o ./obstack.o ./partition.o ./pexecute.o ./physmem.o ./pex-common.o ./pex-one.o ./pex-unix.o ./safe-ctype.o ./sort.o ./spaces.o ./splay-tree.o ./strerror.o ./strsignal.o ./unlink-if-ordinary.o ./xatexit.o ./xexit.o ./xmalloc.o ./xmemdup.o ./xstrdup.o ./xstrerror.o ./xstrndup.o  ; \
      ranlib ./libiberty.a; \
      cd ..; \
    else true; fi
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/Leo/Documents/gcc-cross-iphone-4.6.0/build-x86_64-fedora-linux-gnu/libiberty'
yes
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking stddef.h usability... yes
checking stddef.h presence... yes
checking for stddef.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for strings.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/file.h usability... yes
checking sys/file.h presence... yes
checking for sys/file.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for obstacks... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for ssize_t... yes
checking for uintptr_t... yes
checking for ptrdiff_t... yes
checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
checking size of int... 4
checking size of long... 8
checking for clearerr_unlocked... yes
checking for feof_unlocked... yes
checking for ferror_unlocked... yes
checking for fflush_unlocked... yes
checking for fgetc_unlocked... yes
checking for fgets_unlocked... yes
checking for fileno_unlocked... yes
checking for fprintf_unlocked... no
checking for fputc_unlocked... yes
checking for fputs_unlocked... yes
checking for fread_unlocked... yes
checking for fwrite_unlocked... yes
checking for getchar_unlocked... yes
checking for getc_unlocked... yes
checking for putchar_unlocked... yes
checking for putc_unlocked... yes
checking whether abort is declared... yes
checking whether asprintf is declared... no
checking whether basename is declared... no
checking whether errno is declared... no
checking whether getopt is declared... yes
checking whether vasprintf is declared... no
checking whether clearerr_unlocked is declared... yes
checking whether feof_unlocked is declared... yes
checking whether ferror_unlocked is declared... yes
checking whether fflush_unlocked is declared... yes
checking whether fgetc_unlocked is declared... yes
checking whether fgets_unlocked is declared... no
checking whether fileno_unlocked is declared... yes
checking whether fprintf_unlocked is declared... no
checking whether fputc_unlocked is declared... yes
checking whether fputs_unlocked is declared... no
checking whether fread_unlocked is declared... yes
checking whether fwrite_unlocked is declared... yes
checking whether getchar_unlocked is declared... yes
checking whether getc_unlocked is declared... yes
checking whether putchar_unlocked is declared... yes
checking whether putc_unlocked is declared... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for nl_langinfo and CODESET... yes
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for catalogs to be installed...  be ca da de el es fi fr id ja nl sv tr uk vi zh_CN zh_TW
checking for uchar... 
checking for ld used by GCC... ld
checking if the linker (ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for shared library run path origin... done
checking for iconv... yes
checking for iconv declaration... install-shextern size_t iconv (iconv_t cd, char * *inbuf, size_t *inbytesleft, char * *outbuf, size_t *outbytesleft);
configure: updating cache ./config.cache
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depdir commands
mkdir -p -- .deps
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/Leo/Documents/gcc-cross-iphone-4.6.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can someone help me with this? Thanx!

Comment: I think 'make -t' will show a trace of the commands being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never Mind. I tried it again, and I got configuration arm-apple-darwin not supported. oh well.